# Matlab Get Handle for Layout

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

As the title states, I need to get a handle for my Matlab application.  My class is derived from `matlab.apps.AppBase` and is `app.UIFigure` (if that matter, I'm still learning Matlab).  My main goal is to change the mouse cursor to `watch` after a button is clicked and data is processed in the background.

I have tried:

```
set(gcf,'Pointer','watch')
```

But gcf is just empty, so it creates a new figure.  I have also gotten all of the figures, using:

```
figs = findall(groot,'Type','Figure')
```

Which finds all of the figures I am using.  I believe that I need to get the overall application figure and find the handle, but I am unsure how to do that.

Comment: The input arguments are: the class, `ButtonPushedData`.  I don't see the handle in either.  Could you give an example?

Comment: Ah, you're using the App Designer. I don't have much experience with that yet. The first input argument to your callback is `app`, you should be able to do `app.UIFigure.Pointer = 'watch'`?

Comment: Hmm... the warning I received included: `Functionality not supported with figures created with the uifigure function.`

Comment: Interesting... The App Designer windows and UI elements are different from the “classical” ones, and they’re also not as complete yet (new functionality is added every release). It is very conceivable that these figures don’t allow changing their mouse cursor. I don’t know.

Comment: That was my fear.  And I'm struggling finding documentation...

Answer (score 1):

There is no `pointer` property for `uifigure`; otherwise, you would be able to use `app.UIFigure.Pointer = 'watch'` as suggested by @CrisLuengo.

However, specially for `uifigure` MATLAB provides a nice looking and powerful progress bar [`uiprogressdlg`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uiprogressdlg.html). You can make it indeterminate with `uiprogressdlg.Indeterminate = on;`. I find this working pleasingly well.

Here is an example:

```
f=uifigure;
progressdlg=uiprogressdlg(f,'Title','Progress','Message', 'Doing something please wait', 'Indeterminate','on');

pause(10); % Run your algorithm.

% Delete the progress bar after work done.
progressdlg.delete();
```

[image]

Comment: Nice alternative! (also, you now have edit privileges! yay!)

Comment: Yeah, I’m using that in other parts of the app, but in my current part, for various reasons, I’d like to have the mouse change. Oh well...